switching tabs is not working in selenium-python
I am writing small python script to open a webpage and click a link which redirects to next page. I have to then click export button which downloads the file.
When the control goes to second webpage, I get error "unable to locate the element".
I am unable to print the list of elements in that page.
Here is the code snippet to change the window and getting all the elements in the second window
   original_window = driver.current_window_handle
    assert len(driver.window_handles) == 1
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[normalize-space()='Devices By Machine / Login Name']").click()

    time.sleep(1)
    handles = driver.window_handles
    print(handles)
    print(handles[1])
    driver.switch_to.window(handles[1])
    time.sleep(1)
    print(driver.current_url)
    print(driver.title)
    time.sleep(20)

    all_elements = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "div")
    for element in all_elements:
        print(element.text)

    buton = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//td[@id='PDFButton']//a[contains(text(), 'PDF')]").click()

